# Switching UITabBarController tabs from a separate UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view that has a couple of buttons and I have a tab bar view controller with two different tabs.
When I press one of the buttons in the view controller I want to jump to a specific tab in the tab bar view controller.

How would I go about this?

Comment: This is different because the buttons are not in the tab view or tab bar controller. They are in a completely different view.

Comment: Either edit to include those details and try to get it re-opened, or ask a question that makes those details clear. Your question now focuses on selecting a certain tab rather than dealing with the complexity of communicating with a tab bar controller from a view controller that's not in one.

Comment: I apologize I should have said I have view CONTROLLER and a tab bar view controller.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Or just `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;`. Same thing. Also, note that we're assuming here that this code lives in the view controller -- view controllers have a `tabBarController` property.

Comment: The buttons and the tabs are in two different view controllers.

Comment: If they are in separate view controllers "self" wont work will it?

Comment: yes they will not work. because self means this, current object or in this case UIViewController

Comment: That's what I thought. I need to transition from one view to another while selecting a specific tab. Not simply jumping between tabs.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you pass a reference to the tabBarController to this new controller and use the above method?

Comment: I've tried this in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear and initWithNibName and it always loads on the first tab.

Comment: how you are going from one view to another?

Comment: you can use prepareForSegue and in this method you can assign a property of the destination Controller may be a tab id 0,1,2,3.. and then in destination controller in viewDidLoad method just select that tab